# Shorttitle in collections in biblatex

Tags: biblatex

I'm using the style verbose-trad2 in `biblatex`. I have some bibliographical `incollection` items which refer to a `collection` item via the field `crossref`. The `collection` item has a `shorttitle` item which unfortunately is not being used, as you can see in this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[style=verbose-trad2]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{stack2.bib}
\begin{document}
  The first one\footcite{vasquez1998bajo}. \par

  And then\footcite{negredodelcerro1998}.
\end{document}
```

And the items:

```
@collection{MartinezRuiz1998,
 editor =       {Martínez Ruiz, Enrique},
 title =        {España y Suecia en la época del Barroco (1600-1660)},
 shorttitle =   {España y Suecia},
 year =         1998,
 location =     {Madrid},
 }

@InCollection{negredodelcerro1998,
 author =       {{Negredo del Cerro}, Fernando},
 title =        {Contradicciones en la Monarquía Católica},
 pages =        {667-685},
 crossref =     {MartinezRuiz1998}
 }

@InCollection{vasquez1998bajo,
 author =       {Vasquez Lopera, Julián},
 title =        {Bajo el signo de la diplomacia etc.},
 crossref =     {MartinezRuiz1998},
 pages =        {761-791}
 }
```

Is there a way to force biblatex to check whether a `collection` item has been already cited through an `incollection` item?

Comment: Do you want to achieve "Fernando Negredo ... In: [1]"?

Comment: @Martin: I want to achieve: Fernando Negredo ... In: España y Suecia, op.cit. That is: I want the shorttitle to be used and not a repetition of the whole title of the collection item.

Comment: Have a look at the `philosophy-verbose` style. It implements the `@inbook`/`@incollection`/`@inproceedings` by printing only the `@in` information and then actually citing the `crossref`'d or `xref`'d `book`/`collection`/`proceedings`. This will give something very close to your wishes.

Comment: There also is [biblatex : avoid redundant information](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/172669/35864) now, which seems quite related.