# biblatex : avoid redundant information

Tags: biblatex

I'm exploring the great possibilities of biblatex ... and there are a few questions I can't resolve.

I'll start :) with one (edit !) of them :

I'm using "crossref" to cite several chapters in a book. Currently, when a second chapter in the same book is cited, all information about the publisher etc is reprinted. I'd like only the first reference to the book to have the full information, the following chapter could just have "author, chapter, in : bookname, **op. cit.**"

Something tells me this should be possible ... would you know how to achieve this ?

Thanks in advance,
Jos

Here's a small code :

```
\documentclass[ngerman,french]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}

\makeatletter
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{perpage}
\MakePerPage{footnote}
%% Biblatex %%
\usepackage[language=french,%
autopunct=true,%
  citestyle=verbose-trad2,%
   strict,% 
   citepages=suppress,% 
   idemtracker=true,% 
   loccittracker=true,%
   opcittracker=true,%
  related=false,
      bibstyle=reading,entryhead=false,entrykey=false,annotation=false,abstract=false,library=false,file=false,%
backend=biber]%
{biblatex}%

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{MH_Holzwege,
  keywords =     {MH,D},
  author =   {Martin Heidegger},
  title =    {Holzwege},
  publisher =    {Vittorio Klostermann},
  address =      {Frankfurt a. M.},
  year =     2003,
  series =   {Einzelausgabe des Bd. 5 der Gesamtausgabe},
  edition =      {8., unver\"{a}nderte Auflage},
  addendum =     {1. Publikation: 1950}}

@InBook{MH_Kunstwerk,
  keywords =     {MH,D},
  author =   {Martin Heidegger},
  title =    {Der Ursprung des Kunstwerkes},
  pages =    {1--74},
  crossref = {MH_Holzwege}
}

@InBook{MH_NietzscheGott,
  keywords =     {MH,D},
  author =   {Martin Heidegger},
  title =    {Nietzsches Wort `{Gott} ist tot'\,},
  pages =    {193--247},
  crossref = {MH_Holzwege}
}

@InBook{MH_Weltbild,
  keywords =     {MH,D},
  author =   {Martin Heidegger},
  title =    {Die Zeit des Weltbildes},
  pages =    {69--104},
  crossref = {MH_Holzwege}

@Book{MH_SZ,
  keywords =     {MH,D},
  author =   {Martin Heidegger},
  title =    {{Sein und Zeit}},
  address =      {T\"{u}bingen},
  publisher =    {Max Niemeyer},
  year =     2001,
  edition =      {18. Auflage},
  addendum =     {1. Publikation: 1927}}
    }

\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\addto\extrasfrench{\providecommand{\og}{\leavevmode\flqq~}\providecommand{\fg}{\ifdim\lastskip>\z@\unskip\fi~\frqq}}

\begin{document}

\title{Titre}


\author{A. Teur}

\maketitle

Texte\footcite[20]{MH_Kunstwerk}.

Plus de texte \footcite{MH_Weltbild}.

Et hop \footcite{MH_SZ}

Une derni\`ere\footcite{MH_NietzscheGott}

\printbibliography[title={Oeuvres de Martin Heidegger},keyword=MH,keyword=D] 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome here! For the future, you're better off asking one question in each post.

Comment: Ad 2: Have a look at [`biblatex-publist`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-publist). This will change the bibliography style for all bibliographies though, at present it is not really possible to change the bibstyle between two `\printbibliography` statements (see also [biblatex: different bibstyles in the same document?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/170358/35864)).

Comment: OK, than I'll stop looking for a way to resolve problem n. 2, thanks for telling me. And my question reduces itself to number 1.

Comment: Maybe you would like to edit your question then to remove #2 (you can ask a *new* question about issue #2 later, if one arises).

Comment: No. 1 is one of the most infuriating aspects of switching to `biblatex`. Mostly, things are so much nicer but then there are these odd bumps in it where it can't cope with stuff easily managed by `bibtex`. (The 'In' issue is another one.)

Comment: As it stands now, what you want seems to be quite hard to achieve, since there is no way (AFAIK) for `biblatex` to know whether an entry with the same `crossref` has been cited before (we could check if the `crossref` is in the bibliography though [this will always give `op cit.`, not what you want], we could also find out if the `crossref` has been cited before, also not exactly what you want.)

Comment: As I see it, one would have to define a new tracker, like `ifentryrefused` (read as "ref[erence; i.e. `xref` or `crossref`] used", not "refused" `:-)`), that toggles to `true` (for an entry `foo`), if another entry (let's call that entry `bar`) that `crossref`'d or `xref`'d `foo` has been seen before (i.e. `bar`'s `\ifciteseen` yields true). That is, `\ifentryrefused{foo}` is true iff there is another entry that ref's (`xref`s or `crossref`s) `foo` (let that particular entry be known as `bar`) and if `bar`'s `\ifentryseen{bar}` yields true. I'd love to be proved wrong though.

Comment: It's not me who's going to prove you're wrong ... Thanks for the information ; btw, I edited my question to remove issue no. 2. Maybe a workaround (for issue 1, the only one remaining here) would be to print only a limited amount of information in the footnote, and have the full record in the bibliography ? I'll look for a way to distinguish between fields that are printed in the footnotes and in the bibliography tomorrow.

Comment: There is some support for that with `style=philosophy-verbose` that maybe used for inspiration. (If you just try your example with that style you have to define the bibliography string 'cited' for French, though.)

Comment: We can certainly find out if we are in a citation or bibliography situation (there are `\ifcitation` and `\ifbibliography` for that, p. 178 of the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf)). So limiting the information depending on where it is to be found is not a problem.

Comment: Indeed, phylosophy-verbose seems to be able to handle this : "With the verbose style, when citing \@incollections entries, the data of the \@collection are
printed entirely in the first citation and shortened afterwards. Anyway in the final bibliography the
@incollection is always complete of all the informations about the corresponding \@collection." But how should the 'cited' string be defined ?

Comment: The bibstring `cited` can be defined with `\NewBibliographyString{cited}\DefineBibliographyStrings{french}{cited = {cit\adddot}}`.

Comment: OK, thanks, I missed the `\NewBibliographyString` command. This works like a charm ! I could have thought that writing a philosophy paper would require `biblatex-philosophy` sooner or later ... but thanks for convincing me ! But there are other answers below that I'll have to look at ... this "comment and answer' interface kind of confuses the new user that I am.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think it can be done, without undue difficulty. Here's a sort of proof of concept:

```
\newbibmacro*{cite:seen:related}{%
 {\xifinlistcs{\thefield{crossref}}{blx@bsee@\the\c@refsection}
   {}
   {\listcsxadd{blx@bsee@\the\c@refsection}{\thefield{crossref}}}}}

\newcommand{\ifrelatedunseen}[2]{%
  \xifinlistcs{\thefield{crossref}}{blx@bsee@\the\c@refsection}
   {#2}
   {#1}}

\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \usebibmacro{cite:citepages}%
  \global\togglefalse{cbx:fullcite}%
  \global\togglefalse{cbx:loccit}%
  \bibhypertarget{cite\the\value{instcount}}{%
    \ifciteseen
      {\iffieldundef{shorthand}
         {\ifciteibid
            {\usebibmacro{cite:ibid}}
            {\ifthenelse{\ifciteidem\AND\NOT\boolean{cbx:noidem}}
         {\usebibmacro{cite:idem}}
               {\usebibmacro{cite:name}}%
             \usebibmacro{cite:title}}%
          \usebibmacro{cite:save}}
         {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}
      {\ifboolexpr {
         test {\iffieldundef{crossref}}
         or not ( test {\ifentrytype{inbook}}
               or test {\ifentrytype{incollection}} ) }
       {\usebibmacro{cite:full}%
        \usebibmacro{cite:save}}
       {\ifrelatedunseen
        {\usebibmacro{cite:seen:related}%
         \usebibmacro{cite:full}%
         \usebibmacro{cite:save}}
        {\usebibmacro{related:info}}}}}}

\newbibmacro*{related:info}{%
  \usedriver{}{inbook:rel}}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{inbook:rel}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{in:}%
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
  \newunit%
  \bibstring{opcit}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}
```

Basically: we modify `cite` so that it looks for a `crossref` in `inbook` or `incollection` types. If there is one uses the (ordinary) method for seeing if the `crossref` has been previously cited, and calls a modified macro (which in turn calls a revised driver) if it has. If the `crossref` not been previously cited (directly or indirectly) it calls a macro which records the citation of the `crossref` as if it had been cited.

It's a bit rough of course; "production" code would need to deal with (e.g)

- shorthands (as well as "op. cit"), and perhaps idem and ibid as well, but I don't see insuperable difficulties, though the cite saving mechanism would need to be modified to deal with the "note" classes.
- (perhaps) the `incollection` type separately from `inbook` (since one might want to print editors' names)
- `xref` fields as well as `crossref` (which is what I have used, since that was what was in the MWE) (and I've always found the `xref` mechanism rather difficulty in any event)

It does have certain merits, however: if the "main work" is cited, the citetracker picks it up automatically. And if there is a `\citereset`, it works as it should (i.e. we lose the op.cit.)

This code inserted (between `\makeatletter ... \makeatother` into the above MWE gives the following.

[image: output]

Comment: Great answer +1. Maybe you would like to switch between `blx@bsee@` and `blx@fsee@` depending on `\iffootnote`, as I understand it, the former is for the body text, the latter list for footnote citations. (I'm not sure, if this will work properly though.)

Comment: @moewe You may well be right! I was in rather a rush, and I'm sure there are quite a number of refinements which would be desirable to make this robust enough to be general. I'll try experimenting a little this evening.

Comment: Great! It would be good to see quite a generally-applicable and robust solution, as this is a question that comes up from time to time, and has not received a satisfying answer (I think).

Comment: for your information, I have adapted this code to a package http://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-opcit-booktitle